R / Using pivot_longer in dplyr / I want the count values in my columns to be the number of rows after pivoting
Here is a mock dataset of a much larger dataset I am working with. I am trying to change to a longer format where I have more rows, and each row reflects an observation of a single mosquito.
# Package:
library(dplyr)

# Dataframe:
mock <- data.frame(village = c('A', 'A'),
                   season = as.factor(c('dry', 'wet')),                
                   trap = as.factor(c('BS', 'MET')),
                   mosquito1 = as.numeric(c(3, 3)),
                   mosquito2 = as.numeric(c('2', '0')))

I tried this code:
# Attempt to pivot_longer:
mock_longer <- mock %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = mosquito1:mosquito2,
        names_to = "mosquito_species",
        values_to = "Count")

In this case, the two mosquito species are in one column, "mosquito_species", but I also have an additional column, "counts", counting the number of each mosquito species that was caught with a specific trapping method.
I want R to look at the count values of each mosquito column before pivoting, and then use these as the number of new rows (I hope this makes sense!). I would want my dataframe to look like this one after pivoting:
# What I want: 
mock2 <- data.frame(village = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
                   season = as.factor(c('dry', 'dry', 'dry', 'dry', 'dry', 'wet', 'wet', 'wet')),                
                   trap = as.factor(c('BS', 'BS', 'BS', 'BS', 'BS', 'MET', 'MET', 'MET')),
                   mosquito_species = as.character(c('mosquito1', 'mosquito1', 'mosquito1', 'mosquito2', 'mosquito2', 'mosquito1', 'mosquito1', 'mosquito1')))


You can add %>% uncount(Count) to your code.

Many thanks!! this worked. Also, another solution that was mentioned in another post worked:
data.frame(expandRows(mock_longer, "count")) ```                                                                 I will use the "uncount" function so I don't have to use a new package.
